# How do I remove &nbsp; in IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, html-entities

I have some javascript code which removes non-breaking-space.
It doesn't work in IE, however it does work in Chrome/FF/Safari.

Wonder if someone can tell me why... ?

```
<table id="shelf">
<tr class="row_products">
    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<!-- C5_5 --> some content...</td>
    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<!-- C5_2 --> some content...</td>
    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<!-- C5_3 --> some content...</td>
    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<!-- C5_1 --> some content...</td>
    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<!-- C5_6 --> some content...</td>
    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<!-- C5_4 --> some content...</td>
</tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
document.getElementById("shelf").innerHTML = document.getElementById("shelf").innerHTML.replace(/&nbsp;/g,"");
</script>
```

This code is directly after a table with id #shelf. I only have limited control of the output of my software, thus the non-breaking-spaces which needs to be removed (because it breaks the page design/look).

Hope everything is clear! Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
document.getElementById(\"shelf\").innerHTML = document.getElementById(\"shelf\").innerHTML.replace(/\&nbsp[ ]*\;/gi,"");
```

Comment: Sorry, this did not make any difference

Comment: @kempe upload some html for test